# android code to Open folders in my PC from android

Tags: android, windows, connection

I want to create a client application for android and a server app for PC.

Such as if I perform a tap event on my android device the folder on the PC should open.

I wanted to create my mobile phone as remote and control the PC via that Phone.

Comment: You should read about socket connections in details. I think you should create a server side app which will constantly send the file structure info to the android client and use this info to display file info in android device. Again see socket connection usage in great detail.

Comment: @ Mr_Hmp Thank You for your attention... But socket programming is not the issue for me .... but the issue is how can i preform the events like click,pointer move, scroll etc on my phone that reflect on the  computer screen..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said earlier use socket programming to send data from android and receive it.

On the server side i.e pc you can use java to scroll, mouse move, keyboard functionalty.

See my [Blog on doing mouse clicks, scrolls using Robot class](http://erraticcodes.blogspot.in/2014/03/small-java-program-to-operate-mouse.html), Use [Robot class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) in java to perform these functions.